# Google Tag Manager Form Submission with Formik

Tags: reactjs, forms, submit, google-tag-manager, formik

Try as I may, I am unable to successfully track any form submissions with Google Tag Manager when the form is submitted by Formik in a React project.  I have tried every possible variable, trigger, tag option that I can find.  Nothing.  gtm.formsubmit is never firing.

Any ideas why?

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem? I'm having the same problem and the answer below did not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Event has to be prevent before send to formik. My current workaround:

```
const handleSubmit = event => {
  formFormik.handleSubmit(event.preventDefault());
};

<form id="form-test" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
 ...
</form>
```

Comment: This solution does no longer work for me, do you know if this changed with an update? I am using Formik v2.2.9